# How to save the output of an IPython console to a file in Spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have a bug in my program :(

The problem is that:

- My `.py` code is long, and takes ages to run
- I don't know where the bug is

The **good news** is that I have a lot of `print()` in my `py` file, so I can potentially know where the bug lives.

The **bad news** is that my bug makes my computer *crash*, so there is no way for me to look at the output of the `ipython` console and see what went wrong.

How can I have the output be written to disk while the program runs? So that I can still open the file after reboot to understand what happened before the crash?

This question is different from [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python), because I need

- continuous writing to file
- something to use from within Spyder

Many thanks!

Comment: Write to a file instead of using print statements? Use the Logger [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)? Use the debugger instead of print statements? Oh, actually just remembered another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: Thanks @AlbertRothman but I have no idea how to do that. Can you post that as an answer and explain what to do please?

Comment: Yeah, your question is pretty much a duplicate of the post I linked above. Look there.

Comment: thanks but that does not work. I want to see at the errors thrown by `pandas` and other. and any other output in the console. my `print` statements allow me to understand were I am in the code, but I need the full text in the console

Comment: then also redirect the std err to file using the same method as redirecting the std out

Comment: please just post the code ! :D

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Very interesting question! Fortunately IPython has the right magic for you. It's called [`%logstart`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-logstart) (please follow the link for the full documentation).

To start using it and save the input and output of all your commands, just type in an IPython console

```
In[1]: %logstart -o
```

and that will record your session from that moment on into a file called `ipython_log.py` placed in your current directory.

`%logstart` is very flexible, so you can select a different file to save to, and also how you save your session (either pure Python or as IPython commands).

Comment: Thanks! IPython has a lot of little treasures like this one :-)

Comment: @carloscoroba on a side note, any new version of anaconda coming soon? thanks again for your great work

Comment: Anaconda 4.3 will come out the last week of January or first of February 2017, and it'll include Spyder 3.1.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, it seems `%logstart -o` only logs out put if there is `Out[n]`, but if there is a `stdout` it doesn't capture that. Is there a way to capture the `stdout` in `ipython`, especially if there is no `Out[n]`?