# Write shell output into a text file

Tags: python, shell

How can I write the shell output in to a text file in python? I want to save the shell output as a log in a text file and I am currently using spyder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just using print statement or print(statement), use:

a) some logging modules. Have a look at `logging` module for example.

b) an opened file for the output and write everything to that file. So in your script:

```
fout=open('log.txt','w')
# Here are your script things....
fout.write(statement+'\n')
# More script things ...
fout.close()
```

c) use an example from this post: [How to save the output of an IPython console to a file in Spyder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754285/how-to-save-the-output-of-an-ipython-console-to-a-file-in-spyder)